# How to retrieve lightning component quick action in VS code

Tags: vs-code, package.xml

How to retrieve lightning component quick action in VS code. When i retrieve the layout it is showing the quick action for visual force components only. Do any one know how to fix this. My package.xml is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">         
<types> 
    <members>*</members>      
    <name>Layout</name>     
</types>     
<version>45.0</version> 
</Package>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the cloud symbol and look for quick actions:
[image]

Comment: Yes but when I check the quick action in the page layout it is not showing

Comment: Are you talking about this:
https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/why-quick-actions-are-not-appearing-on-case-page-layout-in-lightning-experience/